# Safety of epoxy resins in direct and constant contact with drinkable water

Tags: water, waterproofing, water-pressure, water-damage, epoxy

So I live in a flat on a six-flats building and thus it has a tank of water in the basement to provide pressure to the tap water of all the taps in the building. Recently the administrator of the building decided to do something with the tank without asking the neighbours. He called a construction company and asked them to waterproof the tank using epoxy resin. They worked on it without saying something to the neighbours and painted with that epoxy all the walls of the tank. (Meanwhile the used another tank, as the building has two.)

Now, on Thursday they reconnected the water to the tank after the curation period was supposed to be passed completely and all the neighbours began to feel a very bad and unpleasant smell to paint, glue or dissolvent coming out of the taps when using the water. That was so much like this that another neighbour came to my house saying that we should not drink the water. I repeat that we didn’t know what was done.

To shorten out, I talked with the administrator about this and told me what he had done. But the only solution that he gave to me is to let the epoxy resin cure for longer! But I and other neighbours want it out of our water tank. The experience made us feel unsafe on our own house. We do not know to what amount of dissolvent we were exposed.

That cannot be solved, but now my question is how safe is to have that water tank coated (in the inside, so direct contact with the water!) with epoxy in general? I heard that long exposition to epoxy resins (even cured) might be mutagenic and carcinogenic because of the presence of epichlorohydrin on it.

And now the solution is not clear at all for me. Is it possible to just put that resin out of the tank or the process would be worse that just letting it there, as I suppose it would require absurd amounts of solvents?

Comment: To answer it, we need details on the process and chemicals used. If you can afford it  there are labs that will test the water.

Comment: @RohitGupta Will they test the water directly of they need to know beforehand which substances concern me? I am not a chemistry expert and I only know partly the process that was done. I can request more information from the administrator but this is not being very collaborative after what he has done.

Comment: Your local health department should have something to say about this.  Most places would require permits and testing to be done for community water source/s.  It almost sounds like someone did not want to get the permits.

Comment: If the epoxy was strictly on the outside of the tank to reinforce it, there shouldn't be an issue at all. Sounds like there were holes, cracks, whatever that were coated to stop leaks and that some of the epoxy seeped into the tank. Did they drain the tank first of just switch supply to the spare tank, then switch back? If they didn't drain the tank, then the epoxy got into the water through whatever they were trying to patch up.

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry, I forgot to mention that the epoxy painting was set in the inside, so in direct contact!

Comment: We don't do biological safety here. That's a medical concern. Best of luck.

Comment: @isherwood Well, Home Improvement is directly related to not having poisonous water in your improved water tank, I guess. Anyway...

Comment: Your primary question isn't about waterproofing a tank. It's about the effects of unknown chemicals on the human body. The distinction is stark. Feel free to revise to more clearly ask about remediation and I'll cheerfully retract my close vote. Be sure to include product information, as the question is too vague without that, leaving it about dispute resolution, which is no more on topic.

Comment: @isherwood My question is about the adequacy of a painting material to be used for a very particular task and if that is a correct use of such material.

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt there, but again, _product information_. And once you have that you have the literature for said product and no longer need us.

Answer (score 4):

Go back to your administrator and ask exactly what product was used. If they have it, you can read the label and instructions to see if it says it's suitable for use in a potable water system. Or contact the manufacturer to find out what they say.

Answer (score 0):

> He called a construction company and asked them to waterproof the tank using epoxy resin.

Good choice. Food grade epoxy is an excellent material for coating insides of tanks.  Food and soda cans are lined with it, as well.

It is a *2-part* material.  Those have a basically nontoxic "A" part and a "B" part including a binding agent that is typically an immune system irritant, such as BPA or hexamethylene diisocyanate (though I wouldn't expect an epoxy to use diisocyanate).  Perfectly mixed, each binding agent will grab two A-parts, making a perfect A-B-A-B-A-B forever chain that is *one single, continuous molecule*.   It isn't relying on between-molecule bonds like stone, but *intra*-molecule bonds, which are stronger.

Of course it's never perfectly mixed, and "the bad situation" would be to have a surplus of B-part.  Some epoxies are very forgiving of this and assure any surplus binding agent is neutralized. Others require proper mixing, but the product is supplied with an intentional deficit of the binding agent, to allow a significant mixing tolerance and still have all the binding agent consumed. For this reason, use instructions should be followed carefully.

> I talked with the administrator about this and told me what he had done. But the only solution that he gave to me is to let the epoxy resin cure for longer

Well, that's correct, but the installer should have known that.  The equipment should not have been placed in service if the cure time hadn't run based on local conditions. Cold extends cure time.

They also should have filled and purged the tank a couple times.   If the odd taste persists after that, I'd be concerned.

> But I and other neighbours want it out of our water tank. The experience made us feel unsafe on our own house. We do not know to what amount of dissolvent we were exposed...
>
> I heard that long exposition to epoxy resins (even cured) might be mutagenic and carcinogenic because of the presence of epichlorohydrin on it.

Now that *will* kill you.

All that pseudoscience.  The genuine fear you're choosing to cultivate, stacked on top of your "learned helplessness" and sense of doom - yeah. That can make you sick and kill you.

I don't know whether your epoxy was improperly mixed or placed in service prior to cure.  But you don't know either - **it's a mystery of science!**

I hope you understand I'm being sarcastic, and the entire point of science is so you can *actually know* things instead of suffer in uncertainty.

And what else isn't a mystery is the chemicals in use.  Every workplace is required to carry [Safety Data Sheets](https://www.hse.gov.uk/chemical-classification/labelling-packaging/safety-data-sheets.htm) which list every chemical in them.   The company who did this work will have SDS's for every chemical used in the preparation and coating of the tank, and they will be typically *happy* to share them with you because it quiets such concerns. However all you really need is the product names, and you can simply google up the safety data sheets.

The data sheets will list particular chemicals, so you don't have to test the water for mystery chemicals... just those.  That makes things a lot easier.

Now talk to a lab, get some sample bottles and follow instructions and get your water tested.

> Is it possible to just put that resin out of the tank or the process would be worse that just letting it there, as I suppose it would require absurd amounts of solvents?

**No solvent will remove epoxy**.  The two parts cure into a third, long-chain molecule which is immune to its own solvent, and any other paint solvent known.  Even aggressive strippers may not work.

I would *media blast* to near white metal with an inert media like good old sand (will need PPE for the crews, silicosis is not good) and then reapply a coating everyone agrees with.  Which basically means I hope you enjoy the taste of rust :) Or you'll be replacing the tank with a plastic tank. Plastic: what could go wrong?

Comment: First of all, let me thank you for your detailed answer. However, I noticed a certain towards me when you talked about the "pseudoscientific horsecrap" that you think I am spouting and then I want to ask you about how pseudoscientific is the fact that most polyepoxide products contain traces of epichlorohydrin, which is know to produce skin cancer. Read under "cancer risks" here: https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2016-09/documents/epichlorohydrin.pdf Btw, speaking about pseudoscience: I would enjoy much more taste of rust than taste of epichlorohydrin in my water, as rust is nontoxic.

Comment: @Hvjurthuk "Most polyepoxide products" **aren't food grade**.  Your claim there is not actually based on the epoxy that was used in your tank, nor any testing of your water.  Actual science is HARD. You can't just "go with the feeling", you have to be skeptcal about everything and test everything.  I told you how: identify the products used, read the CSDS's and have a lab test for listed chemicals.  The real risk for you is that by the time you finally get serious, the taste and chemicals will have faded, and you won't get any results at all.

Comment: "The real risk for you is that by the time you finally get serious, the taste and chemicals will have faded, and you won't get any results at all", well if that happens and there is nothing dangerous in my water then I won't have any problem. I personally avoided using tap water during this period... I just want to be sure for the future as I would like to generally feel safe using water to cook, drink and clean when I am in my own house.

Comment: @Hvjurthuk Well, then, you should really do testing *even if there was no tank at all* just to a) have a baseline, and b) to identify what local filtration (if any) is needed to bring water to your personal standards.  Who knows? The government might put chloramine or some crud in there easily removed by a carafe filter. That'd be nice to know.  But also get those CSDS's and test for that. Epoxy done right is fine - otherwise you're already dead from canned foods and drinks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGZyT9vGraw